# List cell values if criteria met in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I am working on a formula that will yield the following result:
 - Checks value of cells (B2:B) and returns the value of cells (A2:A) if the value is less than or equal to 'x'.

See this image for reference. 
[image]

The expected outcome here would be:
 - E2: Raking leaves, Shoveling Dirt
 - E3: Doing Laundry
 - E4: Changing Spark Plugs

I can get the formula working on a basic level (per row) with this:

```
=IF(B2:B = 1,A2:A ,null)
```

I don't know how to go about comma-separating the titles in ONE cell like I've put in my example though. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `filter` for the criterion

```
FILTER(A2:A, B2:B <= 1)
```

If you want them all in one cell you can `join` the resulting range together like this

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER(A2:A, B2:B <= 1))
```